# Implementing SSH Server in C#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

A project we're working on just got a new requirement added to it: it has to be able to receive files through SFTP (SSH) using key/pair authentication. We've been able to find an interesting collection of SSH **client** libraries (such as SSH.Net), but no server ones. The closest we've found so far is a Python library that we're debating implementing through IronPython.

How should we go about doing this? Are we missing any libraries, or should we work on implementing it ourselves?

Comment: Any reason why you can't just run a separate SSH server?

Comment: You don't want to implement one yourself - it's too easy to get the security protocol wrong.  OpenSSH itself has had it share of issues: http://www.openssh.org/security.html

Comment: We can run a separate SSH server, and that's our fallback at the moment, but it means added complexity to the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Also, FxSsh is a pure C# implementing SSH server side. In this stage, supported EXEC method and return stream.

you are welcome Fork and Contribute on https://github.com/Aimeast/FxSsh

Answer (score 0):

Rebex Tiny SFTP Server is a minimalist SFTP server written in C#. You can find sources at https://github.com/rebexnet/RebexTinySftpServer. It depends on a commercial component though.

The list of SFTP server components which will enable you to write your own server application can be found at https://www.sftp.net/server-libraries. I am aware of only two of them: one is from nSoftware (originaly from Eldos) and one from Rebex.