# Implement SFTP server in .NET

Tags: .net, ssh.net

I need to implement SFTP **Server** within .net core project.
I realize the most commonly used library for SSH is  [SSH.net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) but I didn`t found anything about server implementation using the library, Only SFTP clients.
Does anyone have any experience creating an SFTP server using the library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing SSH Server in C#/.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456377/implementing-ssh-server-in-c-net)